# customize FMX.InAppPurchase.Android unit in delphi xe7

Tags: android, delphi

I want to customize **FMX.InAppPurchase.Android** in the path : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\source\fmx` .
When i changed any code this unit , unit compiled by previous code , for example original unit code

```
  ServiceIntent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(StringToJString('com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND'));
  ServiceIntent.setPackage(StringToJString('com.android.vending'));'

customize unit code

  ServiceIntent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(StringToJString('xxx.bind'));
  ServiceIntent.setPackage(StringToJString('com.xxx.xxx'));
```

i want my app connection to other billing service(xxx),but when app running ,app connection to play store .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create customized version of `FMX.InAppPurchase.Android` in your project folder and add it to your project `Project` -> `Add to Project`.

When you do that Delphi will compile and use your customized version instead of original one.